# Problems with Date, preparedStatement, JDBC and PostgreSQL

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I Have to get a movie from a PostgreSQL database that matches a given title and release date.
title is a character(75) and releaseDate is a date. I Have this code:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM \"Movie\" WHERE title = ? AND \"releaseDate\" = ?)";
Connection conn = connectionManager.getConnection();
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(releaseDate.getTime());
stmt.setString(1, title);
stmt.setDate(2, date);
ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery();
```

but it's not working because the releaseDate is not matching when it should.
The query `SELECT * FROM "Movie" WHERE title = A_MOVIE AND "releaseDate"` = A_DATE works perfectly on a command shell using psql

Comment: If `releaseDate` is a `java.sql.Date`, why copy it to `date` before calling `setDate()`?

Comment: is not java.sql.Date is java.util.Date

Comment: What's the exact SQL column type of `releaseDate`? Is it really `date`? There is also `timestamp`. Which PostgreSQL DB version and JDBC driver version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in the database because of time format was changed from dd/MM/YYYY to MM/dd/YYYY.

Thanks

Comment: Aha! http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT